# I am getting this error PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel' not found in

Tags: database, sales-order

```
<?php

namespace Mastering\Blowhorn\Model;

use \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class Blowhornmodel extends AbstractModel
{
    public function _construct()
    {
    $this->_init('Mastering\Blowhorn\Model\ResourceModel\Blowhornmodel');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Magento running in `developer` mode? What happens after you've run `composer install` or `composer update`? Is the file in `vendor/magento/...` etc.? Linux machine?

Answer (score 0):

Replace  `use \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel` with `use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel` . I am suggesting to remove slash.
`Edited:` - You can see in this picture the class file is present and its not 404.
[image]

Comment: I tried that, but it is showing the same error.

Comment: How and Where you getting this error - during setup:upgrade ?  and may you please post the full error or may be error log. I need some more information to debug it.

Comment: I am getting this error when i am running this particular file.

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Mastering\Sample\Model\News.php
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Mastering\Sample\Model\News.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Mastering\Sample\Model\News.php on line 7
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Mastering\Sample\Model\News.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Mastering\Sample\Model\News.php